# How does "indexOf()" method work and where can it be used?

Tags: java, iterator, listiterator

I'm new to Java and is trying to learn the concept of iterator. I saw the code below from [Java Tutorial Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html), however, I am struggling to understand the function of this method and how it could be used. Could someone provide me with an example of how to use this method as part of an working code and explain it to me how it works?

```
public int indexOf(E e) {
    for (ListIterator<E> it = listIterator(); it.hasNext(); )
        if (e == null ? it.next() == null : e.equals(it.next()))
            return it.previousIndex();
    // Element not found
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: you have list like {a,b,c,d,e} and you use indexOf method like list.indexOf(a); and it will return 0 because a is at 0 at list. if you use list.indexOf(e); it will return you 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a method for finding the index of an element `e` (of generic type `E`) that may (or may not) be contained by the underlying `Collection`. If present, it uses `it.previousIndex()` to return the index value for the element. Otherwise, it returns `-1`.

Comment: but shouldn't  "for (ListIterator<E> it = listIterator(); it.hasNext(); )" be written as "for (ListIterator<E> it = list.listIterator(); it.hasNext(); )" where list is an reference to an instance of ArrayList or LinkedList?

Comment: @TonyStark Not if the method is part of a type that itself implements `List`. Here it is using `this.listIterator`.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping out! I was just wondering if you could put this code snippet as part of a working example? To be honest, I'm still not entirely comfortable with it and I think a working example will help me out greatly. Sorry for all the trouble. Thanks again!

Comment: It's a possible implementation of [`ArrayList.indexOf(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-). Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

The indexOf() method is used to find the index of a particular character, or the index of a particular substring in a string. Keep in mind that everything is zero indexed (if you didn't already know). Here is a brief example:

```
public class IndexOfExample {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       String str1 = "Something";
       String str2 = "Something Else";
       String str3 = "Yet Another Something";

       System.out.println("Index of o in " + str1 + ": " + str1.indexOf('o'));
       System.out.println("Index of m in " + str2 + ": " + str2.indexOf('m'));
       System.out.println("Index of g in " + str3 + ": " + str3.indexOf('g'));
       System.out.println("Index of " + str1 + " in " + str3 + ": " + str3.indexOf(str1));
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Index of o in Something: 1
Index of m in Something Else: 2
Index of g in Yet Another Something: 20
Index of Something in Yet Another Something: 12
```